# Merge sort C# Implementation

Tags: c#, sorting, mergesort

Its been years (10+) since I have worked with sorting algorithms directly.  So I have been trying to go over them again to refresh my memory. The thing is my ideas of how to do it doesn't seam to match the way I have the tutorials doing it.

Does it matter?  Assuming that my code is working I would almost mean that its correct.  However I have also been looking into the Big-O I really cant remember ever seeing this before.  I would almost think that if you code it incorrectly it will slow things down and mess up the performance.

```
public class MergeSort2
    {


        public MergeSort2()
        {
            var data = Util.CreateData.CreateRandomIntArray(200);  // just a method that spits out an array of ints
            var sortedData = Sort(data);

        }


       private int[] copyArray(int[] A, int start, int end)
        {

            int[] result = new int[end-start];

            int cnt = 0;
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                result[cnt] = A[i];
                cnt++;
            }

            return result;
        }


        public int[] Sort(int[] data)
        {

            if (data.Length <= 1)
                return data;

            var length = data.Length / 2;

            int[] LeftArray = copyArray(data,0,length);
            int[] RightArray = copyArray(data, length,data.Length);

            Array.ForEach(data, a => Console.Write(a + ","));
            Console.Write("\r\n");
            Array.ForEach(LeftArray, a => Console.Write(a + ","));
            Console.Write("\t - \t");
            Array.ForEach(RightArray, a => Console.Write(a + ","));
            Console.Write("\r\n");


            RightArray = Sort(RightArray);
            LeftArray = Sort(LeftArray);

            var sorted = merge(RightArray, LeftArray);

            Console.Write("Sorted: ");
            Array.ForEach(sorted, a => Console.Write(a + ","));
            Console.Write("\r\n");

            return sorted;
        }

        public int[] merge(int[] right, int[] left)
        {


            int[] merged = new int[right.Length + left.Length];

            int cntright = 0;
            int cntleft = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < merged.Length; i++)
            {
                if (cntright == right.Length)
                {
                    merged[i] = left[cntleft];
                    cntleft++;
                }
                else if (cntleft == left.Length)
                {
                    merged[i] = right[cntright];
                    cntright++;
                }
                else if (right[cntright] <= left[cntleft])
                {
                    merged[i] = right[cntright];
                    cntright++;
                }
                else
                {
                    merged[i] = left[cntleft];
                    cntleft++;
                }
            }

            return merged;
        }



    }
```

So I guess my question is two fold:

1. How is my implementation of merge sort?
2. Does it matter that I'm implementation isn't exactly the same as everyone else?

Comment: Some links worth checking: [General naming rules from .NET Framework Design Guidelines](https://brunolm.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/net-framework-design-guidelines/), [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042(v=vs.110).aspx), [Internal Coding Guidelines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2005/01/26/internal-coding-guidelines/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Advice 1**

Since I have very little exposure to C#, I will confine myself to efficiency: you can use double buffer strategy in order to eliminate **`copyArray`**, which will increase performance of your mergesort:

```
public static void coderoddeMergesort(int[] array)
{
    coderoddeMergesort(array, 0, array.Length);
}

public static void coderoddeMergesort(int[] array, int index, int length)
{
    // Do the sanity checks for input. I am not a C# programmer so don't know.
    int[] aux = new int[length];
    Array.Copy(array, index, aux, 0, length);
    coderoddeMergesort(aux, array, 0, index, length);
}

private static void coderoddeMergesort(int[] source,
                                       int[] target,
                                       int sourceOffset,
                                       int targetOffset,
                                       int rangeLength)
{
    if (rangeLength < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    int middle = rangeLength / 2;

    coderoddeMergesort(target,
                       source,
                       targetOffset,
                       sourceOffset,
                       middle);

    coderoddeMergesort(target,
                       source,
                       targetOffset + middle,
                       sourceOffset + middle,
                       rangeLength - middle);

    coderoddeMerge(source,
                   target,
                   sourceOffset,
                   targetOffset,
                   middle,
                   rangeLength - middle);
}

private static void coderoddeMerge(int[] source,
                                   int[] target,
                                   int sourceOffset,
                                   int targetOffset,
                                   int leftRunLength,
                                   int rightRunLength)
{
    int targetIndex = targetOffset;
    int leftIndex = sourceOffset;
    int leftIndexBound = leftIndex + leftRunLength;
    int rightIndex = leftIndexBound;
    int rightIndexBound = rightIndex + rightRunLength;

    while (leftIndex != leftIndexBound && rightIndex != rightIndexBound)
    {
        target[targetIndex++] =
            source[rightIndex] < source[leftIndex] ?
            source[rightIndex++] :
            source[leftIndex++];
    }

    Array.Copy(source, leftIndex, target, targetIndex, leftIndexBound - leftIndex);
    Array.Copy(source, rightIndex, target, targetIndex, rightIndexBound - rightIndex);
}
```

Now, I will briefly explain the idea behind the double buffer strategy.
You give two arrays to the sorting method. The one is the source array from which we pick elements, and another one is the target array in which we put merged runs.

At the very beginning of sorting (**`coderoddeMergesort(int[], int, int)`**) we create an auxiliary buffer **`aux`** that contains the exact copy of the range to be sorted. The very first call in **`coderoddeMergesort(int[], int, int)`** treats **`aux`** as a source array, and **`array`** as the target array. For that reason the sorted stuff ends up in the **`array`**.

It is very hard to explain formally, but try to think about the fact that we keep alternating the roles of **`aux`** and **`array`**. And since we have two arrays, we do not need to allocate any more memory: the merge operation merges from source to target. See the following figure:

[image: Double buffered merge sort]

On random **`int`** arrays of length 2 million I get the following results (removed console I/O from your version, of course):

> ```
> Seed = 636123215194590270
> OP mergesort in 2473 milliseconds.
> coderodde mergesort in 1767 milliseconds.
> Algorithms agree: True.
> ```

**Advice 2**

It would seem from MSDN that the signature of your sorting routine should be:

```
public static void myFunkyMergesort(int[] array, int startIndex, int length)...
```

**References**

If you want to see both your and mine version against each other, you can find everything [here](https://gist.github.com/coderodde/4888cb403ea108ba456b4bbcb17497fd).

Hope that helps.

Comment: You sir are amazing.  This is exactly what I was after.  I have seen this example think its like the one on Wikipedia I just couldn't get my head around why you would want to go that crazy with it when my solution would work just as well.    So the point of an algorithm isn't just to get the correct output for the input its to do it at the best speed.    I am going to go digest this see if I can get it to work will come back with any questions.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, efficiency is not only about time, it's also about saving energy.

Answer (score 7):

Inside of your `copyArray` you should not have the `cnt` variable separate from the for loop, you should just include it in the declaration. The name of that Method should be in *PascalCase* not in *camelCase*.  You should also give operators some space (ie `[end - start]`)

so this:

> ```
>    private int[] copyArray(int[] A, int start, int end)
>     {
>
>         int[] result = new int[end-start];
>
>         int cnt = 0;
>         for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
>         {
>             result[cnt] = A[i];
>             cnt++;
>         }
>
>         return result;
>     }
> ```

would become this

```
private int[] CopyArray(int[] A, int start, int end)
{
    int[] result = new int[end - start];
    for (int i = start, cnt = 0; i < end; i++, cnt++)
    {
        result[cnt] = A[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

you can remove the `cnt++` from inside the loop and just add it to the for loop declaration.

---

Variables should be *camelCase*

> ```
>  int[] LeftArray = copyArray(data,0,length);
>  int[] RightArray = copyArray(data, length,data.Length);
> ```

These should be

```
 int[] leftArray = CopyArray(data,0,length);
 int[] rightArray = CopyArray(data, length,data.Length);
```

And

> ```
> public int[] merge(int[] right, int[] left)
> ```

should be

```
public int[] Merge(int[] right, int[] left)
```

Because Methods should always be in *PascalCase*

And

> ```
> int cntright = 0;
> int cntleft = 0;
> ```

should be

```
int cntRight = 0;
int cntLeft = 0;
```

for the same reason

Comment: I am curious as to why PascalCase vs camelCase matters?  Isnt it just developer preference?   I have been using camelCase for 20 years now I am wondering if I should switch :)   Check forgot you can add the cnt in the for loop thanks for that one

Comment: you weren't consistent in your naming either, but yes it does (*sort of*) matter because that is the C# standard for naming variables and methods.  just about anywhere you go will require you to name your variables and methods according to this standard.  I am curious as to what you mean by using camelCase for 20 years, you would use camelCase for variables, but not for methods or class names and if you had, you should have been consistent in your naming scheme

Comment: I normally start all methods with lowercase then up the first letter in words after however I think you are correct that I don't do it all of the time.  ex:  exchangeAuthCode()  the above example was just a test method this is my first time posting here I didn't realize that even that would be reviewed.  Which I guess is a bonus because your right I have become lax with my naming.   I will review my naming standards as well as working on search algorithms.  As you have pointed out it does matter.    Now I need to go clean up some names on the project I am working on :)

Comment: @DaImTo here's the official MSDN capitalization conventions... You'll find that most of us are picky about that around here :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RobH thanks I found this to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx   Pick away.   I have become lax and lazy and I am trying to change that.

Comment: Just to be clear, if you have been using Java for the past 20 years, then camelCase is correct for method names. PascalCase is the C# standard though.

Comment: Java standards aren't C# standards. In Java public methods are `camelCase`, not `PascalCase`. And the curly braces open on the same line in Java and on the next line in C#.

Answer (score 4):

This may seem like a really minor point but try to avoid side effects wherever possible. You want your code to be really obvious to anyone reading it what the main purpose of the code is:

```
 Array.ForEach(data, a => Console.Write(a + ","));
```

I look at the code and think that the main purpose is to iterate the array. In fact, the whole reason for the code is writing the array to the console. That can be done like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", data));
```

For the record, I don't even like that as we're doing 2 things in one line.

```
WriteDataToConsole(data);

...

private static void WriteDataToConsole(int[] data)
{
    var displayString = string.Join(",", data);
    Console.WriteLine(displayString);
}
```

And then you think, hey - I can write any kind of `IEnumerable<T>` here! So you change the method to be more generic:

```
private static void WriteDataToConsole<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    var displayString = string.Join(",", data);
    Console.WriteLine(displayString);
}
```

And now you can output a sequence to the console in one line in a really readable way.

Comment: Actually the only point of the console writing is because I am visual to understand something completely I like to see what its doing.    Now I know you can just use string.join but I personally find Array.foreach sexy any opinion on performance not that it matters when its really just debugging messages.      However your last example is awesome I am going to have to steal that one.

Answer (score 0):

## How is my implementation of merge sort?

You already have a lot of good advice, so I will focus on something else: coding style.

- Avoid acronyms and abbreviations: `cnt` should be `count`
- Avoid [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation): `LeftArray` should be `Left`
- Use [`var`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) when appropriate
- Use interface instead of class/type when appropriate
- Respect [C# Coding Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)
- Fix your indentation ;)

Also XML documentation would be nice

## Does it matter that my implementation isn't exactly the same as everyone else's?

Not really. You may want to check to improve perf, memory, etc. Check in different environments. [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet) should help you.

Comment: Well I guess that answers another of my questions.  I am a big fan of var.  However my manager is not.   I am keeping my vars.  A lot of your comments are me not realizing how "picky" you guys are with code review I will do better next time.

Comment: @DaImTo I think you should use it even more :)

Comment: Would you please elaborate a little bit more on your bullet points in the first section?  This will make your Review much better.  Thanks.